# Using a function within a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, function, md5

I have the following line of code :

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM details WHERE md5(name) = '".md5($input_name)."'");
```

This query works just fine , however , when i change the query to the following :

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM details WHERE salt(name) = '".salt($input_name)."'");
```

The query  doesn't seem to work.

The salt function is as follows :

```
function salt ($name) {


global $salt;



return $salt.$name;

}
```

where $salt is a global variable ( an md5 hash)

Why doesn't the second query work ?

Comment: I don't think salt is a MySQL function, do you not mean to do a SHA and then add the salt to the string?

Comment: yes , and salt() is a function that i've defined myself - as mentioned in the question

Comment: You've created a PHP function not a MySQL function. Also aren't you trying to match a column to a value shouldn't it be  "WHERE name = '".salt($input_name)."'"

Comment: `WHERE MD5() = MD5()` is really pointless. Let me guess that you have just learned about hashing and salting and are trying to retroactively add it to your system? Then you're doing it entirely wrong.

Comment: @deceze Not really . The purpose here , is just to prevent SQL injections. Otherwise , i do know that md5()=md5() is of little use in validation

Comment: Then escape your values or use prepared statements, the usual way to deal with SQL injection. Hashing your whole database for each query is really wasteful.

Comment: @deceze Yeah , i've also used the techniques that you've mentioned. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has no access to functions you define in PHP. You can only use functions that MySQL defines in a MySQL query, or functions that you have written in SQL. You'll have to rethink what you're doing and express it in a way that does not require MySQL to use PHP functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't md5() a PHP function ? How were we using that correctly ?

Comment: `MD5()` also happens to be a function defined in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in PHP and functions in MySQL is two seperate things.

When sending MySQL queries, MySQL will be responsible for parsing the string you are sending. And MySQL doesn't know of any of the PHP code you made - and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt this be easily done by:

```
$saltinput = salt($input_name)
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM details WHERE salt(name) = '$salitinput'");
```

Comment: As mentioned by deceze , salt(name) can't be called from within MySQL , since i've defined it using PHP